# What is an appropriate log cabin base depth?

Tags: foundation, shed

I'm currently in the process of building the foundations for a 5m x 3m log cabin, using sand/cement with a 32mm layer of paving slabs. In accordance with the [Tiger Sheds website](https://www.tigersheds.com/page/build-a-base/) I am laying down 40mm of sand/cement with the 32mm paving slabs on top of that.

Having searched around at other sites I can see that there seem to be a wide array of recommended base depths for log cabins, ranging from 200mm depth down to the 63mm depth quoted by Tiger Sheds. I am a little concerned that the 40mm of sand/cement is not enough.

The ground where I am laying the foundations seems to me to be pretty hard, can anyone advise if the 40mm  depth is adequate?

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. Where are you located, and how deep is the frost line? And, you should probably [take our tour](//diy.stackexchange.com/tour) so you'll know you'll know the details of contributing here.

Comment: A fundamental point is the ground condition and type.

Comment: The frost line and local building codes (if any) are the key criteria.

Comment: Hello, thanks, North East UK, not sure about the frost line, but will search about and see what I can find

Comment: Also is this a single story or more the depth and thickness increase as you go up.

Comment: I should point out that this is a UK style log cabin, which is more comparable to a garden shed than something you'd find in the Alps. So single storey, 40mm pine walls.